# Select Multiple XML nodes in SQL Server to append values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I am trying to append some nodes to an existing XML in the database. The XML looks like the following:

```
<Parameters>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>ColumnsToDisplay</Name>
    <Value>Priority</Value>
    <Value>Description</Value>
    <Value>Asset ID</Value>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

The number of values can vary for each parameter. I'm trying to update the XML by appending a few new values as with the query below. Its a little wonky but it is the only way I could get FOR XML AUTO to work.

```
set @NewXML =
(
select * from 
    (
    SELECT  
        Parameter.C.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(256)') as Name,
        Parameter.C.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(256)') AS Value
    FROM tblSavedReportParameters
    CROSS APPLY ParameterXML.nodes('//Parameter') Parameter(C)
    where savedreportid = @SavedReportID
    union 
    select  'FilterType' as Name, '#All' as Value
    union 
    select  'FilterText' as Name, '#All' as value
    ) as Parameter for xml Auto, elements, root('Parameters') 
)
```

Everything works great except the new XML only returns the first value for each parameter. I've tried a variety of CROSS APPLY and INNER JOINS on the value node and just can't get the syntax down. It currently looks like this:

```
<Parameters>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>ColumnsToDisplay</Name>
    <Value>Priority</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>FilterText</Name>
    <Value>#All</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>FilterType</Name>
    <Value>#All</Value>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

How can I update the query to return all the values for each parameter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
set @NewXML = 
(
  select (
         select T.ParameterXML.query('Parameters/Parameter')
         from tblSavedReportParameters as T
         where T.savedreportid = @SavedReportID 
         ),
         (
         select P.Name, P.Value
         from (
              select 'FilterType' as Name, '#All' as Value
              union all
              select 'FilterText', '#All'
              ) as P
         for xml path('Parameter'), type
         )
  for xml path('Parameters')
)
```

This query builds two XML columns that is then combined using `for xml path('Parameters')`. The first column contains all `Parameters` from the XML and the second column contains all your new `Parameters`.

Comment: Wow, much easier to do it that way. I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks!